# Issue with .htaccess sending http to https

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I want to send all my http traffic to https. This is the code I use in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

This seems to work fine for all pages except the ones in the website home directory.
eg. when I type http://mywebsite.com/index.php it goes to https://mywebsite.comindex.php
It forgets the slash

Comment: If you started out with the wrong rule in your .htaccess, the redirect to the slashless version might have been cached.  Clear your cache and try again?  I can't think of much else, since it looks exactly like [the recipe on the Apache httpd wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

It checks if HTTPS is off.
It will redirect to the https version. You also need to grab the request URI. otherwise it will just redirect to the homepage of your domain.

And little sidenote, you may want to do a 301 redirect. just change the second line to this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Cheers

Comment: It is still not working with your settings. eg. http://cleveridge.org/thanks is still going to https://cleveridge.orgthanks